# Spark - Structured Streaming Kafka (dynamic deserialize)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Suppose we subscribe 2 topics in the stream, one topic is of avro and another one is string, is it possible to dynamically deserialize based on the topic name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, yes

The [`Deserializer`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Deserializer.java#L50) interface accepts the topic name as a parameter, which you could perform a check against.

However, getting access to this in Spark would require your own UDF wrapper around it.

---

Ultimately, I think it would be better if you define two streaming dataframes for each topic of a different format, or simply produce the strings as Avro encoded.